# How to add an outlet to a light switch in this specific situation?

Tags: receptacle, light, dimmer-switch, lamp, cables

I  added an outlet to a light switch (see pictures). But the light switch is not working anymore (was working properly before the outlet addition). The ceiling light is on and is controlled by the lamp switch now. The lamp is not turning on. My connections seem good.
Cable is a #14 electric cable. Light switch is a Cloudy Bay in Wall Dimmer Switch for LED Light.

What am I missing? Why the lamp switch is controlling the ceiling light now? And why the lamp is not turning on?

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

**Before:**
[image]

**After**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A switch is only connected to to live and switch live wires.  An outlet needs live and neutral.  Neutral must be white, but white does not mean neutral.  You wired it wrong.

Comment: Do I have to find a neutral? Or can I create one? There are only 2 cables in the light switch box: a black one and a white one.

Comment: It seems that you have an old style switch loop.  They used one cable(black and white) to control the light, but the white was used has hot/live.  The proper way is to replace that cable with three wire(black, red and white) cable, so you can bring neutral down to the switch.

Comment: Please don’t take this wrong, but the ‘after’ pic tells me that you need to get a bit of the basics down before touching wires. There are books in the library that cover basic wiring. A cheap multimeter will help you identify which wires are doing what. This is all totally learnable, but mistakes can damage property (without insurance paying out, I might add) and hurt people.

Comment: @crip659. Got it. I see what u mean now. Well, I am not sure I can go thru the walls like that. Not sure it is worth the time and effort. Maybe I will switch to a camera with battery instead.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it is similar but I didn't want to install a combo switch/outlet for esthetic and functional reason.

Comment: I wasn't trying to suggest the combo but rather to point you to an explanation of the switch loop neutral problem and some possible solutions.